# Foundation 5 Range Slider - method for dynamically setting start/end/step

Tags: zurb-foundation

The range slider allows for initialization of the start/end and step values via the data-options in the markup but doesn't provide a method like set_value for changing these values at runtime with reflow.

Am I missing something? Tried resetting the data-options and calling reflow but that didn't redraw.

Jw

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely a hack, and I only know that it works in Chrome...

```js
function updateSliderRange(left,right,value){
    value = (value)? value : left; // default to left if unspecified

    var data_options = "display_selector: #sliderOutput; start: "+left+"; end: "+right+";";
    // set the new options
    $('#slider').attr('data-options',data_options);
    // clear the styles
    $('#slider span').attr('style','');

    // push the html back to break DOM bindings
    $('#slider')[0].outerHTML = $('#slider')[0].outerHTML;

    // get foundation to rebind
    $(document).foundation('slider','reflow');
    $('#slider').foundation('slider','set_value',value); // set the slider
}
```